# What is our policy regarding questions with close to zero research?

Tags: discussion, policy

Today I found these two questions:

[Beep Beep..is Road Runner Real?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61245/beep-beep-is-road-runner-real)

[What was the first full-length film that was a musical?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61228/what-was-the-first-full-length-film-that-was-a-musical/)

These are just two examples of questions whose answer can be found easily with a search engine or Wikipedia:

[answer to the first question](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=roadrunner&atb=v29-2__&t=h_&ia=meanings)

[answer to the second question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_film#The_classical_sound_era)

The OP clearly put no effort looking for the answer: what is the site policy in this case?

Comment: Related? - http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/306/should-movie-trivia-questions-be-closed

Comment: @Paulie_D Though, trivia is not the same as easily answerable, even if sometimes related. What this question is talking about are questions that are too simple and easy to google (for which a downvote might already be sufficient). "Trivia" means "nobody cares", not "everybody knows".

Comment: More relevant: [Should we close questions that can be easily solved by reading the subject's Wikipedia page?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2300/49)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The irony...

Comment: @mattiav27 What's ironic?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That I did not find that other question...

Comment: @mattiav27 I don't think your question relates only to this site. This is a serious issue that affects almost all SE sites. I downvoted the two questions and will move on.